# grunt (minimatch/glob) folder exclusion

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, glob, gruntjs

I have a situation where I'm trying to use grunt to lint a codebase, excluding specific folders.

grunt uses minimatch (similar to bsdglob) under the hood to match files, but I can't seem to figure out how to do a .gitignore style exclude of a folder.

I'd like to ingest this:

`ignoreme`

and match these:

```
/folder/path/here/to/something/ok.js
/another/folder/path.js
/test.js
```

but not match these:

```
/folder/ignoreme/something.js
/folder/path/here/to/ignoreme/metoo/file.js
```

This will match everything, including ignoreme:

```
/**/*.js
```

So I figured I could do something like:

```
/**/!(ignoreme)/**/*.js
```

but that matches files in the ignoreme folder.

I'm used to regexes, but can't seem to figure out how to repeat a pattern or something here - I also tried stuff like:

```
/(!(ignoreme)|*)*/*.js
```

hoping the container would repeat, but that doesn't work, it just fails to match everything.

Any way to either pass a regex to grunt file paths, or make this work for me?

## Update:

Here's how I'm currently dealing with this issue:

```
var pattern = /\/ignoreme\//
var files = grunt.file.expandFiles(arrayOfFilesPassedToMinimatch).filter(function(f){
  return !pattern.test(f)
})
```

I'd still be interested if folder excludes are possible in minimatch.

Comment: Using `map` is results in `files` containing a array of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values. `filter` will correctly set `files` to be a list of filtered paths.

Comment: Right you are, must have typed at night. Updated the code sample to work.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

In the currently-in-development version 0.4.0a, the `grunt.file.expand` method now supports exclusions, and does so in an arguably less complex way than the underlying minimatch matching library. This is possible because `grunt.file.expand` accepts *multiple* patterns (whereas minimatch only accepts one).

From [the grunt.file.expand documentation](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand):

> This method accepts either comma separated wildcard patterns or an array of wildcard patterns. Paths matching patterns that begin with ! will be excluded from the returned array. Patterns are processed in order, so inclusion and exclusion order is significant.

That means you could specify `['/**/*.js', '!**/ignoreme/**']` and while the first pattern would add all `.js` files to the result set, the second pattern would then remove all `/ignoreme/` files from the result set.

Take a look at the [grunt.file.match unit tests](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/8501765fb7addd073754fabf7a0e779a1a54b122/test/grunt/file_test.js#L60-68) if you're really curious.

Note that the version of grunt offering this functionality hasn't officially been released, but if you're interested in using it in a project, see the [When will I be able to use in-development feature 'X'?](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) FAQ entry.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! This looks like a much more elegant solution to my issue - I'll wait for a stable release, but I'll switch when it's out!

Comment: Worth noting: exclusion patterns only work if they come *AFTER* whatever-it-is-they-exclude has been matched by an inclusion pattern. Was confused by putting my exclusion patterns first.

Comment: `grunt watch --verbose` to see which files are being watched

Comment: That's awesome. Thought I would have to write some weird filter just to ignore a file.