# How to detect same file names in different folders while using Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat

I need to write a concat script using grunt. here is my boilerplate:

```
___js
|____dist
| |____vents
| | |____carousel.js
| | |____compare.js
| | |____style.js
|____src
| |____events
| | |____carousel.js
| | |____compare.js
| | |____styles.js
| |____handlers
| | |____carousel.js
| | |____compare.js
| | |____style.js
```

How can I tell concat task, to concat the files that have the same name in events and handlers folder and put each individual concatenated pair in the dist/vents directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to write advanced concat grunt script that find matches in seperate folders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082257/how-to-write-advanced-concat-grunt-script-that-find-matches-in-seperate-folders)

Comment: I need this too, some news?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problem: I wanted my build to fail if there are files with the same file names detected in given path pattern. I have solved it by writing custom task. You could use grunt.file.expand or grunt.file.recurse [GruntAPI](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.recurse)

Maybe this will help you (this is coffeescript rather than js).

```coffeescript
  grunt.registerMultiTask "noduplicates", "Detects duplicated filenames", () ->
    path = require('path')

    dupFilenamesCounted = {}
    haveDuplicates = false

    options =
      cwd: this.data.cwd

    grunt.file.expand(options, this.data.src).forEach (filepath) ->
      filepathParts = filepath.split(path.sep)
      filename = filepathParts.slice(-1).join(path.sep)

      unless dupFilenamesCounted[filename] is undefined
        dupFilenamesCounted[filename].counter++
        dupFilenamesCounted[filename].filepaths.push(filepath)
      else
        dupFilenamesCounted[filename] = { counter: 0, filepaths: [ filepath ] }

    for filename of dupFilenamesCounted
      if dupFilenamesCounted[filename].counter > 0
        grunt.log.error "Filename: " + filename + ' has ' + dupFilenamesCounted[filename].counter + ' duplicates: ' + dupFilenamesCounted[filename].filepaths
        haveDuplicates = true

    # Fail by returning false if this task had errors
    return false if haveDuplicates
```

Then you define your task:

```
noduplicates:
  images:
    cwd: '<%= pkg.src %>'
    src: [ 'static/**/*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg}' ]
```