# GruntJS - Exclude files from the watch

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

how to exclude certain files from a directory from watched. for eg I have a stylesheets folder I am watching for *.css and create a *.min.css using cssmin. But it keeps going in a loop as the folder watched has a new/changed *.min.css(ending in css).

```
    'stylesheet-css':
        files: ['public/stylesheets/*.css']
        tasks:['cssmin:stylesheet-css']
```

I tried couple of things..

```
'stylesheet-css':
    files: [ '!(public/stylesheets/*.min.css)']  # any thing other than .min.css
    tasks:['cssmin:stylesheet-css']
```

doesn't seem to work

Comment: Here is one.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199092/configure-grunt-copy-task-to-exclude-files-folders

Comment: Have you tried !public/stylesheets/*.min.css ? Without round braces.

Comment: @MaheshSapkal - yes...doesn't pick up any changes not even the .css ones as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the files you want, then the files you don't want (both sets), so something like:

```
'stylesheet-css':
    files: ['public/stylesheets/*.css', '!public/stylesheets/*.min.css']
    tasks:['cssmin:stylesheet-css']
```

For reference, see [Grunt globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns).

Comment: I tried it previously. It was not working. but now it seems to. Thanks