# How to configure grunt copy task to exclude .js files from a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, copy, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I am using `grunt-contrib-copy` to copy folders and files from my `src` folder to `build` folder. But I want to exclude all `.js` files from the app subdirectory in my `src` directory.
This is my Gruntfile. But it is copying all `.js` files from the subdirectories in app directory instead of excluding. What changes should I make to make it work.

This is my grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // Task configuration.
concat: {
  dist: {
    src: ['src/app/**/*.js'],
    dest: 'build/app.min.js'
  }
},
    copy: {
    main: {
      files: [
         //includes files within path and its sub-directories
            //{src: ['src/**', '!/src/app/**/*.js'], dest: 'build/', filter: 'isFile'}
        {expand: true, src: ['src/**', '!/src/app/**/*.js'], dest: 'build/', filter: 'isFile'}
      ]
    }
} 
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
 grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'copy']);
};
```

Reference: [Configure grunt copy task to exclude files/folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15199092/2469747)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to remove the first slash after the exclamation mark? So change this:

```
'!/src/app/**/*.js'
```

to this:

```
'!src/app/**/*.js'
```