# Grunt postcss task exclude files

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, task

I am trying to set up `postcss grunt task`, i am wanting to run the task on all files in **css/** except **default.css**, how do i exclude certain files?

**This is my task**

```
        options: {
            processors: [
                require('autoprefixer')(),
                require('cssnext')(),
                require('precss')()
            ]
        },
        dist: {
            src: 'css/*.css',
            exclude: 'css/default.css'

        }

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure grunt copy task to exclude files/folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199092/configure-grunt-copy-task-to-exclude-files-folders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somthing like:

```
    dist: {
        src: ['css/*.css', '!css/default.css']
    }
```

should do the trick.

Have a read of the docs on [grunt.file.match](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.match)

> Match one or more globbing patterns against one or more file paths. Returns a uniqued array of all file paths that match any of the specified globbing patterns. Both the patterns and filepaths argument can be a single string or array of strings. **Paths matching patterns that begin with ! will be excluded from the returned array. Patterns are processed in order, so inclusion and exclusion order is significant**.

Comment: Perfect, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Checkout out the [docs](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file#grunt.file.expand).

> Paths matching patterns that begin with `!` will be excluded from the
>   returned array. Patterns are processed in order, so inclusion and
>   exclusion order is significant.

```
options: {
    processors: [
      require('autoprefixer')(),
      require('cssnext')(),
      require('precss')()
    ]
  },
  dist: {
    src: ['css/*.css', '!css/default.css']
  }
```