# Exclude subdirectory in Grunt-contrib-copy

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I'm copying some folders with grunt-contrib-copy. I'm trying to exclude a subdirectory in the root. I can prevent the contents of the _sprites folder from being copied, but inevitably the sprites copy is always copied. How do I prevent the folder from being copied? Here is what I have:

```
...
copy: {
    deploy: {
        cwd: "src/",
        expand: true,
        src: [
            "**/*",
            "!**/_sprites/**/*"
        ],
        dest: "deploy/"
    }
},
...
```

I've attempted `!_sprites`, `!_sprites/` and others, but none appear to yield the results I want.

Comment: Did you have a look at these? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161119/grunt-contrib-copy-ignore-folder-when-copying http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199092/configure-grunt-copy-task-to-exclude-files-folders

Comment: First link resolved the issue. `**/_sprites/**`