# Grunt task svgmin

Tags: gruntjs, minify

Following the setup [for grunt svgmin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-svgmin) when I run grunt I get the following error

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.
```

[My grunt file](http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/t3C3C/1/)
[MY package.json file](http://jsfiddle.net/makingthings/9ZLbs/)

I get the above error in terminal when I run grunt I know its something silly Im doing as its all new to me but have spent a coupl eof hours trying to work it out.

Comment: Please edit your question or post a comment instead of editing my answer, what error shows up with the Gruntfile you linked ?

Comment: Have you run `npm install` ? Also remove all the useless comments that may have inpact on your Gruntfile

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar error. In my case this error happens when the tools tries to optimize webfont-files saved as .svg. You can avoid this error by [ignoring the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12633119/621765) of the fonts (with an `!` before the path) or specify the directory where svgs are stored like:

```
dist: {
    files: [
        {
            expand: true,
            cwd: basePath,
            src: ['images/**/*.svg'],
            dest: 'dist/your_path',
            ext: '.svg'
            // ie:
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the `grunt` command, you need to register a `default` task that load some others, like the `svgmin` one.

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['svgmin']);
```

Remember that you need to install `grunt-svgmin` with npm :

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-svgmin
```

And load it in your `Gruntfile` just before your registerTask

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svgmin');
```

Here an example extracted from their GitHub Readme.

```
grunt.initConfig({                                                                 
    svgmin: {                                                                      
        options: {                                                                 
            plugins: [ { removeViewBox: false }, { removeUselessStrokeAndFill: false } ] 
        },                                                                         
        dist: {                                                                    
           files: {                                                               
                'dist/figure.svg': 'app/figure.svg'                                
            }                                                                      
        }                                                                          
    }                                                                              
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-svgmin');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['svgmin']);
```

Comment: hello - any idea how i can svgmin multiple files or directories at the same time?

Comment: @danielCrabbe Specify multiple properties in the `files` object?

Comment: yes -  have several svgs to process and even better a wildcard for all svgs in assets/img/ compressed to dist/

Comment: That was an answer, I mean try to specify them in the `files` object property ;)

Comment: oh - i've tried adding a few other files but must be getting the format wrong. Also tried the below but obviously not so clued up on some grunt basics!