# What is the glob pattern matching all files that don't start with an underscore ignoring those in directories that start with an underscore?

Tags: node.js, glob, minimatch

Given the directory structure:

```
a/
  b/
    _private/
      notes.txt
    c/
      _3.txt
      1.txt
      2.txt
    d/
      4.txt
    5.txt
```

How can I write a glob pattern (compatible with npm module [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob)) which selects the following paths?

```
a/b/c/1.txt
a/b/c/2.txt
a/b/d/4.txt
a/b/5.txt
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
// Find matching file paths inside "a/b/"...
glob("a/b/[!_]**/[!_]*", (err, paths) => {
    console.log(paths);
});
```

But this only emits:

```
a/b/c/1.txt
a/b/c/2.txt
a/b/d/4.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some trial and error (and the help of [grunt (minimatch/glob) folder exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632029/grunt-minimatch-glob-folder-exclusion#answer-12633119)) I found that the following seems to achieve the results that I was looking for:

```
// Find matching file paths inside "a/b/"...
glob("a/b/**/*", {
    ignore: [
        "**/_*",        // Exclude files starting with '_'.
        "**/_*/**"  // Exclude entire directories starting with '_'.
    ]
}, (err, paths) => {
    console.log(paths);
});
```