# Grunt Files Object Format: All regular files files immediately under top level directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, minimatch

I can't figure out for the life of me how to get this work. The grunt configuration for a module I'm using ([grunt-sloc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sloc)) requires the [Files Object Format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format). Using this, I want to be able to match all regular files (i.e., non-directories) immediately under the top level directory.

For example, say this is my directory structure, where `+` signifies a directory and `-` signifies a regular file:

```
repo
  + dir
    - unwanted.js
  - server.js
```

How do I use Grunt's [Files Object Format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format) to match `server.js` but not `dir` or `dir/unwanted.js`?

This is how it would look in the [Compact Fomat](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#compact-format):

```
mine: {
  src: [
    '*'
  ]
}
```

Or, in bash, you would get them like this:

```
ls -p | grep -v /;
```

Here's what I've tried with the [Files Object Format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format):

- This does not work:

  ```
  mine: {
    files: {
      '.': ['*']
    }
  }
  ```
- Neither does this:

  ```
  mine: {
    files: {
      './': ['*']
    }
  }
  ```
- Not even this:

  ```
  mine: {
    files: {
      './': ['*/server.js']
    }
  }
  ```
- Nor this:

  ```
  mine: {
    files: {
      './': ['server.js']
    }
  }
  ```
- This works, but it runs recursively, which I do not want:

  ```
  mine: {
    files: {
      './': ['**/server.js']
    }
  }
  ```

After doing a bunch of testing and code reading, I've verified that it is in fact the [minimatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimatch) package (a depencency of Grunt), which is not returning the matches I'm looking for. So it is not the grunt module I am using; it's my grunt configuration.

Since Grunt is so popular and this seems like a very common use case, I'm guessing that there's a way to do this. Does anyone know what that is?

#### Update

As `RobC` pointed out, my last example does *NOT* work. It was picking up `server.js`'s in my `node_modules` directory, which made me think it was working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly FWIW, your examples listed using the [Files Object Format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format) method also did not work for me, including your last one:

```js
 // Although this worked for you, this failed for me...
 mine: {
     files: {
         './': ['**/server.js']
     }
 }
```

The only way I could get this to work was to match everything and then negate the top level directories using Grunt [globbing](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) patterns.

Whilst the following gists demonstrates what worked for me, it does require knowing/configuring the names of the top-level directories you wish to exclude:

#### Directory Structure

Given a directory set up as follows:

```
repo
│
├─── dir
│   │
│   └─── unwanted.js
│
├─── foo.js
│
├─── Gruntfile.js
│
├─── node_modules
│   │
│   └─── ...
│
├─── package.json
│
└─── server.js
```

#### Gruntfile.js

...and a `Gruntfile.js` configured as follows:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        sloc: {
            mine: {
                files: {
                    '.': [
                        '**', // Match everything and add to the results set.

                        // Explicitly state which directories under the top
                        // level directory to negate from the results set.
                        '!**/node_modules/**',
                        '!**/dir/**',

                        // Files can be negated from the results set too.
                        '!**/Gruntfile.js' // 
                    ]
                }
            }
        }

    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sloc');
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'sloc:mine'
    ]);
};
```

#### Sloc results

Running `grunt` via the CLI correctly resulted in [grunt-sloc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sloc) reporting statistics for two files only, namely `foo.js` and `server.js`.

As expected, stats for `package.json` were omitted due to JSON being a [non-supported](https://github.com/flosse/sloc#supported-languages) language.

#### Additional note:

I found the answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12632029/grunt-minimatch-glob-folder-exclusion#answers-header) fairly informative in explaining how patterns that begin with `!` are excluded from the initial returned array.

Comment: Yeah, you're right; my last example did not work. It was only picking up `server.js`'s in my `node_modules` directory. I think this solution will work for me. Very thorough answer! Thanks so much!